# Async/await call action from React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, ecmascript-2017

I have a method `lookupComplete` in react component that call action `checkIfAssign`, I need wait to response and depend on this response trigger in this method another methods. But recieve `Promise {<pending>} "result"`. How to wait until resolve this action ?

**Component:**

```
export class Test extends Component {
  ....

  lookupComplete = (tagId = this.state.tagId) => 
    this.setState({tagId}, () => {
      let result = this.props
        .checkIfAssign(this.state.tagId, this.props.accessToken)

    result.status 
      ? this.triggerTransition(transitions.ClickCheckTag) 
      : this.triggerTransition(transitions.Test)
    })
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  checkIfAssign: (tagId, accessToken) => 
    dispatch(TagAssignmentActions.checkTagAssignment(tagId, accessToken)),
})
```

**Action:**

```
export const checkTagAssignment = (tagId, token) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: TagAssignmentActionTypes.TagAssignmentChanged,
  })

  let status, assignee, response
  try {
    response = await DeviceApi.checkTagAssignment(tagId, token)

    assignee = response.result.assignee
    status = response.result.status
  } catch (e) {
    if (e && e.status === httpStatusCode.notFound)
      status = TagStatus.NotFound
  }

  dispatch({
    type: TagAssignmentActionTypes.TagAssignmentChanged,
    status,
    assignee,
    response,
  })
  console.log(response, 'response')
  return response
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, the code is difficult to read.

Comment: "I have a method in react component that call action". Please specify the name of the methods, leaving it very explicit.  "But recieve Promise {<pending>} result" . Please specify where is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `await`, you should make your function `async`:

```
lookupComplete = async (tagId = this.state.tagId) => 
...

  let result = await this.props
    .checkIfAssign(this.state.tagId, this.props.accessToken)
```

However, **this is a bad pattern**. The correct one would reading the `status` from your app state. As you can see, your action will update the app state here:

```
dispatch({
  type: TagAssignmentActionTypes.TagAssignmentChanged,
  status,
  assignee,
  response,
})
```

If you're doing redux properly, your `Test` component is probably `connect()`ed to redux. In your `mapStatesToProps` you'd pass the value of `status` from the app state to the `Test` component `props`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  status: state.myNamespaceForTaskAssignment.status,
});
```

Then inside [getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) you'd do the check for:

```
nextProps.status 
  ? this.triggerTransition(transitions.ClickCheckTag) 
  : this.triggerTransition(transitions.Test)
```

Or something like this.